# Teradata SQL repeat insert statement

Tags: sql, teradata

pretty new to teradata and trying to figure out how to repeat a simple insert statement.

I have the following statement

```
Insert into Test (Id) values ((sel max (Id)+1 from test))
```

And I would to repeat this 20 times.

Comment: Please provide sample input data and desired output data.

Comment: Teradata SQL does not support procedural statements outside a Stored Procedure. This needs to be done on the client side. For example, in BTEQ the `=` command repeats the last request.

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of running the statement 20 times

```
create table test_table_1 ( numcol int );

replace procedure test_proc()
begin
  declare rowcnt int;
  set rowcnt = 0;
while rowcnt<20 do 
begin
  insert into test_table_1 select max(coalesce(numcol,null,0))+1 from test_table_1;
  set rowcnt = rowcnt + 1;
end;  
end while;
end;

call test_proc();

select * from test_table_1;
```

But in reality you would simply need an identity column which would preclude the need to insert incremental value 20 times.